# Compute the conjugate of a partition

Tags: code-golf

We will think of a partition as a sequence of non-increasing integers.
For a given partition into \$n_1, n_2, \dots, n_k\$ with \$n_1 \geq n_2  \dots n_{k-1} \geq n_k = n\$ we write it out with \$n_i\$ dots on row \$i\$. So for \$6, 1, 1\$ we would write six dots on the first row, one on the second and one on the third

## Task

Given a partition, you should output its [conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Conjugate_and_self-conjugate_partitions). That is you should output how many dots there are in each column of the dot diagram.  For the input \$6, 1, 1\$ the output should be \$3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1\$.

## Examples

```
5, 2, 1 gives output 3, 2, 1, 1, 1
4, 3, 1 gives output 3, 2, 2, 1
4, 2, 2 gives output 3, 3, 1, 1
3, 3, 2 gives output 3, 3, 2
4 gives output 1, 1, 1, 1
```

Comment: How is the fact that it's a partition relevant?

Comment: @Simd The "context" seems to only make the challenge confusing

Comment: will input always come in desc sorted order?

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz yes

Comment: Can the input contain only one number? If so, please add a test case for that

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/235182/)

Answer (score 11):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)

```
⊒⌾/
```

Try it [here.](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oqS4oy+LwoK4oCiU2hvdyBGIDXigL8y4oC/MQrigKJTaG93IEYgNOKAvzPigL8xCuKAolNob3cgRiA04oC/MuKAvzIK4oCiU2hvdyBGIDPigL8z4oC/MgpA)

Explanation via example:

```
   / 4‿3‿1         # use each element as a count to replicate its index
⟨ 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 ⟩

   ⊒/ 4‿3‿1        # take a running occurrence count
⟨ 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 0 ⟩

   /⁼⊒/ 4‿3‿1      # the inverse of /, applied via ⌾, counts occurrences
⟨ 3 2 2 1 ⟩
```

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
L˜{Åγ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m73MwDQxyTB1wYKlpSVpuhYrfE7PqT7cem7zkuKk5GKo4ILl0WY6hjqGsRAuAA)

```
L        # range, so [6,1,1] is [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1],[1]]
˜        # flatten, [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,1]
{        # sort, [1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6]
Åγ       # run length encode, [3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

If we can have extraneous zeros in the output, then by porting [@frasiyav's great BQN answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266339/92727) we have:

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
L˜ā¢
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m73MwDQxyTB1wYKlpSVpuhbLfU7POdJ4aNGS4qTkYqjYguXRZjqGOoaxEC4A)

```
L˜        # same as previously
ā         # length range, [1, 2, 3, ..., len(arr)] (without popping)
¢         # count each
```

Comment: Nice answer. Here are two 5-bytes alternative: [`Å10ζO`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cKuhwblt/v//R5vpGOoYxgIA) and [`L˜Dê¢`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f5/Qcl8OrDi36/z/aTMdQxzAWAA). I went ahead and posted the first one as [a separated 4-bytes legacy 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266345/52210), since the `0` can be omitted for the legacy version.

Answer (score 7):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) / MATLAB, 17 bytes

```matlab
@(x)sum(1:x<=x,1)
```

Anonymous function that inputs a column vector and outputs a row vector.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0KzuDRXw9Cqwsa2QsdQ83@aRrSptYKRtYJhrCYXkGNirWCMzAHKGEE4xmAZIOc/AA)

#### Explanation

```matlab
@(x)              % Define anynomous function of x: column vector
        1:x       % Range from 1 to (first entry of) x. Gives a row vector
           <=x    % Less than/equal to x? Element-wise with broadcast. Gives a matrix
    sum(      ,1) % Sum of each column
```

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>28</s> 22 bytes

*Edit: -6 bytes thanks to [@Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe).*

```r
\(x)table(sequence(x))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhbbYjQqNEsSk3JSNYpTC0tT85JTgQKaEMlbjFrFqSV-ibmpxRppGskaZjqGOoaamjoKfqE-PppcKHKmOgpGOgoIWWWF9Myy1GKF_NKSgtISBWOINASh6jTRAckS0GmETRtIHI82Y2y2QcQJaDNC1WOoY4jT5yYwQUiQLVgAoQE)

<s>Port of</s> Based on [@Command Master's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266333/55372).

Comment: `table(sequence(x))` is 22 bytes? You get a named vector, but I think that's fair.

Comment: Yeah, me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
b1S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/JMPj/4XZN9///o011FIx0FAxjdRSiTXQUjBFMoKgRiGkMFjWKBQA)

For some reason, I almost feel like I've seen this even shorter as part of a different solution...

```
b1     Convert each element of the input to base 1.
  S    Sum across columns.
```

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands/2649a799300cbf3770e2db37ce177d4a19035a25), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Å1ζO
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cKvhuW3@//9Hm@kY6hjGAgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/w62G57b5/9f5Hx1tpmOoYxirE22qYwSmTXSMobSRjhGQNgbyjWJjAQ).

Doesn't work in the new version of 05AB1E, unless we add `0` or `¾` before the `ζ`.

**Explanation:**

```python
Å1    # Convert each value in the (implicit) input-list into a list of that many 1s
  ζ   # Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns,
      # implicitly using a space " " as filler for unequal length rows
   O  # Sum each inner list, which ignores the spaces in the legacy version of 05AB1E
      # (after which the resulting list is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 26 bytes

```r
\(x)Map(\(z)sum(x>=z),1:x)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuha7YjQqNH0TCzRiNKo0i0tzNSrsbKs0dQytKjQhClanaSRrmOkY6hhqQkUWLIDQAA)

A function taking a vector of integers and returning a list of integers.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>52</s> 50 bytes

-2 thanks to @mousetail

```python
lambda a:[sum(i<x for x in a)for i in range(a[0])]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3jXISc5NSEhUSraKLS3M1Mm0qFNLyixQqFDLzFBI1QcxMELMoMS89VSMx2iBWMxaq0wckmQiSjI421VEw0lEwjNVRiDbRUTBGMIGiRiCmMVjUKDbWiouzoCgzr0QjUUdBXddOXUchTSNRUxNi5oKVcD0QAQA)

Answer (score 5):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 7 bytes

```
I.i.@{.
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FNVUtFK8NYM0UrS3V1LiU99TQFWysFdQUdBQMFKyDW1VNwDvJxW1pakqZrsdxTL1PPoVoPwruZqMmVmpyRr2CsYKRgCIa6VgppCqYgLkLGCCZuAuTCxY0R6k1AihDiRhBRMBNi0YIFEBoA)

- `I.` What is the "insert before" index when inserting into the input...
- `i.@{.` Of each of the numbers 0 through n-1, where n is the first input element.

### [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), straightforward alternate, 9 bytes

```
[:+/#"0&1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FNVUtFK8NYM0UrS3V1LiU99TQFWysFdQUdBQMFKyDW1VNwDvJxW1pakqZrsTLaSltfWclAzRDCv5moyZWanJGvYKxgpGAIhrpWCmkKpiAuQsYIJm4C5MLFjRHqTUCKEOJGEFEwE2LRggUQGgA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 45 bytes

```python
def f(a,j=0):
 for c in-1,*a:a[:c]=c*[j];j+=1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PYxBCsIwFAX3PcXfmcQETFpBIjlJyOITG2yRNJQoeBY33eidehvTVtwNj5n3-qRnvg5xmt73HMRpFpc2QCDIe3OguoIwjOChi0Jyhhqt9s54Znt37vdG_qJmsbBYMKQ2kjVEMNA-8EaQVpDGLmYiGfJyTWGx6dZO884eOSgO0lW24VD_qWyqUL1uym3-Fw)

Takes a list and modifies it in place.

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 34 bytes

```python
lambda a:sum(a[:,1>0]>range(a[0]))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PYxBCsIwFET3OcXHjQlEaauCFNoDeIWaxRcbLTQ_IU2FnsVNQfROvY3Rirt5b4a5v9wQrpbGhy6Ozz7o1X5atGhOZwTMu95wrHKZlokqPdKljpgoIX7LQ2Oc9QGoN24A7IAc09YDQkNgXU08ETmLWMRmjd7jwOsbthyFYOB8Q4Gj1B-cH8dpWe0kZBJSxaqthM0_RZfFtPm6TM37Nw)

#### -4 thanks to @att.

Expects a NumPy array.

Ports @Command Master's pure Python.

Comment: second just `lambda a:sum(a[:,1>0]>range(a[0]))`

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 30 bytes

```r
\(l)rowSums(outer(1:l,l,"<="))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhb7YjRyNIvyy4NLc4s18ktLUos0DK1ydHJ0lGxslTQ1IYpu7krTSNYw0zHUMdTU5AKxTXUUjHQUgDxlhfTMstRiBaDWgtISBWOIOASBVZrogARxqTRCUgbiYlNmjGQahItLmRFYjaGOIdylJlAfLFgAoQE)

Slightly longer compared to [pajonk's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266336/67312), based on [this other answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142047/67312).

Comment: I had something like this drafted, but with `apply` instead of (better) `rowSums`.

Answer (score 4):

## [sclin](https://github.com/molarmanful/sclin), 18 bytes

```
1X>b tpose \+/ map
```

[Try it on scline!](https://scline.fly.dev/#H4sIAJ7cP2UCA4s2VTBSMIxVsAYAg8mRlAkAAAA#H4sIAJ7cP2UCAzOMsEtSKCnIL05ViNHWV8hNLAAAO25ryBIAAAA#)

1 repeated by n, transpose, sum each.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 35 bytes

```haskell
f a=[sum[1|j<-a,i<=j]|i<-[1..a!!0]]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GCpaUlaboWN5XTFBJto4tLc6MNa7JsdBN1Mm1ss2JrMm10ow319BIVFQ1iYyFKbzGylqQWlyhk5hWUliikVhSkJpekpijYKqTkc3HmpJYo5JeWgGRsFdIgarg4gURwSZFPnoKKQnFGfrmCBkyJLVy_poK2toJSTIkSiAYrgqoBCYMUIiRgWri4chMz86AWg50UbaqjYKSjYBirEG0MYUFQLEzeREfBGFneCE0SJASRNEbTCRFCSBpBQwMWgAA)

-1 byte thanks to [matteo_c](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73593/matteo-c)

Basically a port of Command Master's [python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266335/46901)

Comment: [35 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GCpaUlaboWN5XTFBJto4tLc6MNa7JsdBN1Mm1ss2JrMm10ow319BIVFQ1iYyFKbzGylqQWlyhk5hWUliikVhSkJpekpijYKqTkc3HmpJYo5JeWgGRsFdIgarg4gURwSZFPnoKKQnFGfrmCBkyJLVy_poK2toJSTIkSiAYrgqoBCYMUIiRgWri4chMz86AWg50UbaqjYKSjYBirEG0MYUFQLEzeREfBGFneCE0SJASRNEbTCRFCSBpBQwMWgAA)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 44 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map(g=v=>v&&g(--v,b[v]=-~b[v]),b=[])&&b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i5RLzexQCPdtszWrkxNLV1DV7dMJym6LNZWtw5Eaeok2UbHaqqpJf1Pzs8rzs9J1cvJT9dI04g21VEw0lEwjNXUVNDXVzCG8CCIC02piQ5IHlWpEXZ1IBmEOmPs5kFkUNUZ/QcA)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>              // a[] = input array
a.map(g = v =>    // for each value v in a[], using a recursive
                  // callback function g:
  v &&            //   stop if v = 0
  g(              //   otherwise do a recursive call:
    --v,          //     decrement v
    b[v] = -~b[v] //     increment b[v] (set it to 1 if undefined)
  ),              //   end of recursive call
  b = []          //   start with b = []
) && b            // end of map(); return b[]
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 8 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
⍘⊚⊐/⊂⊐∵⇡
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4o2Y4oqa4oqQL-KKguKKkOKIteKHoQoKZiBbNSAyIDFdCmYgWzQgMyAxXQpmIFs0IDIgMl0KZiBbMyAzIDJdCg==)

```
⍘⊚⊐/⊂⊐∵⇡  # [5 2 1]
     ⊐∵⇡  # [⟦0 1 2 3 4⟧ ⟦0 1⟧ ⟦0⟧] range of each
  ⊐/⊂     # [0 1 2 3 4 0 1 0]       join
⍘⊚        # [3 2 1 1 1]             occurrences
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0 [`-Q`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

*-2 bytes from @AZTECCO*

```
mo yl
```

### [Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&flags=LVE&code=bW8geWw&input=WzUsMiwxXQ)

---

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0 [`-Q`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

There must be a shorter way

```
co ü ml
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&flags=LVE&code=Y28g/CBtbA&input=WzUsMiwxXQ)

Comment: You can use y method.. `mo yl` for 5 Bytes

Comment: Note that if the flag you're using is for output visualisation purposes only then it can instead be entered in the input field in my interpreter so that it doesn't change the language when you copy the complete markdown directly from the interpreter.

Answer (score 3):

## Google Sheets, <s>92</s> 86 bytes

`=join(",",byrow(map(split(A1,","),lambda(n,sequence(n,1,,))),lambda(r,len(join(,r)))))`

Put the input in as a text string in cell `A1` and the formula in `B1`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 58 bytes

```rust
|a|(0..a[0]).map(move|i|a.iter().filter(|x|i<**x).count())
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZVDdSsMwFMbL7imiFyUZXZitgnRbH8ObUkqoJxDon006imZP4k0v9KHm03jSKCqDQA7f-f44b-_DqM18vpEtaYRqKSOvqxoMkals6SNU-zGJM7bJysPHaOTm4ZxaYemWc5FvC8Yb0dOmO4JVVnBlYKCMS1W7wU5W7dfrifGqG1tDGfMOn1fBbrVkGNCGHIhVbT-alIQ5ZhURgamHysDTgmj1AoXFUoFTDKBT4lqVGQolXZTcdOURKgzApLpGLWW7VSC0hsGU8HxNUfZri7sTFnDhNMzvIxJH5BZjwzzxs38F8r45dxFJ_nPiC4IDfwjJhYMH_xJitz35i8yz_78A)

Basically a port of Command Master's [python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266335/46901)

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 26 bytes

```
Plus@@PadRight[1^Range@#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277PyCntNjBISAxJSgzPaMk2jAuKDEvPdVBOVbtf0BRZl6Jgr5Dur5DdbWZjqGOYa1OtamOEZg20TGG0kY6RkDaGMg3qq39/x8A)

-12 bytes from @att

Comment: [28 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773yc1L70kQ98hKDEvPdVBuc4tJ7GkJDWvrtqoVu1/QFFmXomCvkO6vkN1tZmOoY5hrU61qY4RmDbRMYbSRjpGQNoYyDeqrf3/HwA)

Comment: [26](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277PyCntNjBISAxJSgzPaMk2jAuKDEvPdVBOVbtf0BRZl6Jgr5Dur5DdbWZjqGOYa1OtamOEZg20TGG0kY6RkDaGMg3qq39/x8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 37 bytes

```
a->Vecrev(vecsum([x^i-1|i<-a])/(x-1))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWN1UTde3CUpOLUss0ylKTi0tzNaIr4jJ1DWsybXQTYzX1NSp0DTU1oYrdEgsKcio1EhV07RQKijLzSoBMJRBHSSFNI1FTU0chOtpUx0jHMBbIMtExhjGMdIxADGOgiFFsLNS0BQsgNAA)

---

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 37 bytes

```
a->[vecsum([t>=n|t<-a])|n<-[1..a[1]]]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWN1UTde2iy1KTi0tzNaJL7GzzakpsdBNjNWvybHSjDfX0EqMNY2NjoYrdEgsKcio1EhV07RQKijLzSoBMJRBHSSFNI1FTU0chOtpUx0jHMBbIMtExhjGMdIxADGOgiFFsrCbEtAULIDQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
ẋ∩@
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCLhuoviiKlAIiwiIiwiWzQsIDIsIDJdIl0=)

```
ẋ    Repeat (each value in list times value)
 ∩   Transpose list
  @  Length of each item in list
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
ＩＥ⌈θΣＸ⁰÷ιθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzexAIgrMnNLczUKNXUUgoF0QH55apGGgY6CZ16JS2ZZZkqqRqaOQqEmGFj//x8dbaqjYKSjYBgb@1@3LAcA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
   θ        Input list
  ⌈         Maximum
 Ｅ          Map over implicit range
      ⁰     Literal integer `0`
     Ｘ      Vectorised raise to power
        ι   Current value
       ÷    Vectorised integer divided by
         θ  Input list
    Σ       Take the sum
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 44 bytes

```
\d+
$*_
\G_(?<=(?=(\2_*,?)+)(_+))
$#1,
\D+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qkaDA9T8mRZtLRSueK8Y9XsPexlbD3lYjxiheS8deU1tTI15bU5NLRdlQhyvGRVuF678Ol47Cf1MdBSMdBUMuEx0FYygN5BtxGYP5RgA) Takes I/O as comma-separated integers but test cases removes and reinserts spaces for convenience. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*_
```

Convert to unary.

```
\G_(?<=(?=(\2_*,?)+)(_+))
$#1,
```

For `1` up to the first array entry, count how many entries are less than or equal the value.

```
\D+$
```

Remove the trailing junk.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 6 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
+⌿≤⌸∘⍸
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=037Us/9R55JHPTsedcx41LsDAA&f=S1MwVTBSMORKUzBRMIbSRgpGQNoYCI0A&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=train&n=f)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 37 bytes

```ruby
->l{l[0].times.map{|x|l-=[x];l.size}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6nOifaIFavJDM3tVgvN7GguqaiJkfXNroi1jpHrzizKrW29n@BQlp0tKmOkY5hbCwXmGOiY4zMMdIxio39DwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>59</s> 53 bytes

```c
i;f(*a,z){for(i=0;z;i+=i<a[--z]&&printf("%d ",++z));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLBioMwEIbveYpB2BLXEUyMXlL7IqWH0K4lsGtLantQfHZXE7VagjnI9yX5h5mc4/Ovqq59r2VJvxU2YVveDNVFIhupo0Lv1TGOm9Nudze6qksafF0gwChqwlB2/YDgomqVHE9FmyND1kkyQzbCDPkG8hEKhBRhjdMJ82HBiouRp3a75YtIjDNs/tbBkxtvY26tK7AWnOYfZTgHLnE8uClmObmUY92f0hUNW1JSWxmmoST3Z/2gQTD8Ocq8lHtp6qViS996zjWY@4INZr5kg8IX7cfC2HDS9fnQEgYA@6I4AOTv/pPMdROu@vXzgNuzHi6BzRDINHffFj55@wA@/TQLMnfe4zn5Bw)

- -1 thanks to @ceilingcat
  `i<=*a;` -> `*a/i`
- Golfed another 5 Bytes by @att.

`for(i=1;i<=*a;)`  loops until we print a[0] times

`i>a[z-1]?`        check i against last value in input

`z--`              move to previous position in input if greater

`:printf("%d ",z`  else print position in input
`,i++)`            and increment printed count

I think there can be a way to iterate i backwards.. e.g. `for(i=*a;i..` but my brains are cooking.

Comment: I was hoping for a C answer. Thank you.

Comment: There you are! We were close to 30 answers without it, I felt sad

Comment: [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZLBioMwEIbveYpB2BLXEUyMXlL7IqWH0K4lsGtLantQfHZXE7VagjnI9yX5h5mc4/Ovqq59r2VJvxU2YVveDNVFIhupo0Lv1TGOm9Nudze6qksafF0gwChqwlB2/YDgomqVHE9FmyND1kkyQzbCDPkG8hEKhBRhjdMJ82HBiouRp3a75YtIjDNs/tbBkxtvY26tK7AWnOYfZTgHLnE8uClmObmUY92f0hUNW1JSWxmmoST3Z/2gQTD8Ocq8lHtp6qViS996zjWY@4INZr5kg8IX7cfC2HDS9fnQEgYA@6I4AOTv/pPMdROu@vXzgNuzHi6BzRDINHffFj55@wA@/TQLMnfe4zn5Bw)

Comment: @att that's a great golfing! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 36 bytes

```
f(l)=[l[l>=i].lengthfori=[1...l[1]]]
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pqkwzsfya1?nographpaper)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jxxuj0y1bk?nographpaper)

This works because we can assume that the input is always in descending order as per [OP's comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/266332/compute-the-conjugate-of-a-partition#comment580757_266332).

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 9 bytes

```
#*<|ZJ1Xg
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCIjKjx8WkoxWGciLCIiLCIiLCItcCA1IDIgMSJd)

Comment: This is really clever! It doesn't quite work as written, since `ZJ` is intended for use with strings (try an input of [14, for instance](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCIjKjx8WkosZyIsIiIsIiIsIi1wIDE0Il0=); the output should be fourteen 1's, with no 2's). However, `ZD` should do what you want. You'll have to find a different way to get rid of the dummy values, though.

Comment: Oh, or here's a better way that lets you still use `ZJ`: `#*<|ZJ1Xg` (9 bytes).

Comment: @DLosc Thanks for the fix! The docs said `ZJ` operated on iterables, which I thought also included lists lol

Comment: It does also work with lists and ranges, but the "join each group of values into a string" part is the problem. If the items in each of the iterables are all the same length, it's fine, but if they're different lengths, [you might not get the result you were expecting](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSboBS7IKlpSVpuhY3_XKsFKKjlRKVFJSSgDg5WSlWIVopBchMTU1Vio3lClBQisos8MrPzLNSAnKivHKAZAVU2CU1LbE0pwQi45LDVQoxFWr4AigNAA).

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 9 bytes

```
.#'=,/!:'
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs9JTVrfV0Ve0UufiSlMwUzBUMATSpgpGYNpEwRhKGykYAWljIDTiAgAEJwlP)

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 41 bytes

Saved some bytes thanks to the comment of @Kjetil S

---

```scala
a=>(1to a(0)).map{i=>a.count(_>=i)}.toSeq
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VU7BSsNAEL3nKx6hhx1Igm0UJLgBj4KeiqcQZE2TspLu1s1WkZAv8VIPevGL-h9-gNtde_Aw8-bNvHkz719DI3qRf1dxqvSrMCquDz_68altLO6EVBgjYNV22DjChFkPBa6NEW_V0hqp1jUVuFfSgnsl8CJ69HKwg-vcOmQ-XSRYJJhTEnrnCfL_1E0XJ5r76YIo8o6dNmBHS1ylwZr-bgFb94PtFRvimVekJWZj59U0xeRVU3SMKLzWFWDL9rm6Ubbm5aki8M-d7dLLAwlesrnVEOyMKNuI7Sh5KbJG75RlDyWXNGVWu8Ww8DEF3O8D_gI)

Comment: One less: `a=>(1 to a.head).map{i=>a.count(_>=i)}.toSeq`

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 3 bytes

```
1D∑
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FksNXR51TFxSnJRcDBVZsD_aVMdIxzCWK9pExxhKG-kYAWljIN8oFqIMAA)

A port of [@Unrelated String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85334/unrelated-string)'s [Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266342/9288).

```
1D∑
1D      Convert to base 1
  ∑     Sum
```

---

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 3 bytes

```
rjŢ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FkuKso4uWlKclFwMFViwP9pUx0jHMJYr2kTHGEob6RgBaWMg3ygWogwA)

A port of [@Command Master](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92727/command-master)'s [05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266333/9288).

```
rjŢ
r       Range
 j      Join
  Ţ     Count occurrences of each unique element
```

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 53 bytes

```
i=split($0,p){for($0=j="";i;i--)while(j<p[i])$++j=i}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v8/07a4ICezREPFQKdAszotvwjIss2yVVKyzrTO1NXVLM/IzEnVyLIpiM6M1VTR1s6yzaw1/P/fVMFIwZDLRMEYTBopGHEZA9lGAA)

Comment: I love an awk answer. But is it possible in bash too?

Comment: @Simd [yes](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifaKthqmCkYKj5Py2/SEMj01alWjkx2iG21jpTV9daU7NaASxunWWTGJ0Za50UnaWtHWubqW0IkrKyrlWo/Z@SmpyTWJSqoFugkPQfAA)

Comment: Can you add it as a separate answer?

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 37 bytes

```powershell
1..($a=$args)[0]|%{($a-ge++$i).Count}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY3LTsMwEEXX9leMIkNj1YlIAuwiRYpgC6Lsqgql7vSlUJfYEUhpvj1MadNS0HgzPvee2ZpPrOwSyzLQpsJOzNOmi8LQF0Uqimph5fhmsrtqaA8WOByKlQxzU29c27WcZz5nKvMz/15BRE8q8BIV9ePJI75TEJ9w/AfeKkh@wfgSUS8@oOSilfy0TigmIGEHj6Z6KPQyeJquUTtoOBMOrcsLiwoEfm3pF2eQgngjVKGtS0fbtZhD1gc5Gz@P8to6837QTDLysFGtNVq77x57wdqsNjBQAwjw42ynrPdKLtAk8/b53nxuUOalP/5Px1nLW959Aw)

Takes a list of integers, returns a list of integers

```powershell
1..($a=$args)[0]|%{($a-ge++$i).Count}
1..($a=$args)[0]|%{                 }  From 1 to the value of the first element number
                   ($a-ge++$i).Count   Return the number of numbers greater than the current iteration count
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 36 bytes

```perl
sub{map{//;0+grep$_>=$',@_}1..$_[0]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYxdb4IwGIWv7a84aToLWecH6C4kOO5N5o13SJp9FGMc0AEmM4TfzgpMF2ya5n2f5/RolX8tGxb7TXF@r5I3XU2n3uzxkCvN5NpnXASynk8mTIazqG48Eme5RUKESwFHYB7BXyN0@6W/ESLRJhYC7l3CGeqW3LQ7/N2TgXY6Z1cE5iQXix1TfS4FUz9afZTq04aPgEnvzweHrDRkzGLL4C4Lu5c6P6ZlTB@engugM6tbBLj2tew6G2zqDDHvPqWCjOi/pFDfoK2ieAHPThwr8NftDtsN90hNml8)

Comment: Welcome back perl! I was worried we would never see you again.

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 8 bytes

Prompts for input:

```
+⌿⊃,⎕⍴¨1
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3tv/ajnv2Pupp1gMKPerccWmH4HyjM9T@Ny1TBSMGQK43LRMEYShspGAFpYyAfRJsAAA)